# Which to be verb do you use when listing items?

Tags: verbs, agreement

I'm confused about what "to be verb" to use when you create a list of items.

I mean when you talk about 3 or 4 items. What "to be verb" goes after "how much"? I read that "how much" always goes with uncountable nouns. So I would use "is" instead of "are"?

For example:

- How much **is** a dictionary, a stapler, and three pairs of scissors?
- How much **are** a dictionary, a stapler, and three pairs of scissors?

Does it have to do with proximity of the countable noun or uncountable noun?

Comment: Hi kan, I don't understand the relevance of the *grammar topic about lists* to *verbs to-be*. Can you please explain the link? Thanks.

Comment: Also, all your nouns are countable.

Comment: I mean when you talk about 3 or 4 items. What "to be verb"goes after how much? I read that how much always goes with uncountable nouns. So I would use" is instead of are?" Unless you're talking about the price of the items?

Comment: I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've tried to highlight what seems to be the core of your question. I've deleted the part about *grammar topic* because it doesn't seem to fit, and I've left out the part in your comment about 'price' because the expressions don't seem to be talking about anything *except* price. Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll back the changes. I've tried to highlight the intent of your question, but if I've misread that intent, you're especially encouraged to edit the question to make it ask what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You ask: Proximity. I assume you mean proximity determines conjugation, and I would say stylistically yes, grammatically no. And some would say, stylistically, no, too.

That unit of speech is called a [phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase), specifically a noun phrase, or a complex noun phrase. The verb "to be" is, in English, conjugated to the subject of the sentence. So if that phrase falls in the predicate, then is depends on the subject.

Example :)

> We are angry, tired, and violent.

Compare:

> He is angry, tired, and violent.

In your example, you could argue that you are omitting "the (total) price (of)," so the fully-formed noun phrase could be:

> "How much **is** the total price of a dictionary, a stapler, and three pairs of scissors?

Colloquially, one would replace this jumble of words with the *pronoun* it, i.e.:

> How much **is** *it?*

Answer (score 1):

"How much" followed by *be* **always** refers to price. If *much* is followed by a noun (which must be an uncountable noun) it refers to quantity.

- How much is a bed?
  *refers to the price of a bed.*
- How much mashed potato [would you like]?
  *refers to the quantity of mash.*
- How much is mashed potato?
  *refers to the unit price of mash.*

Which form of *be* you use is governed by how many items there are in your list.

- How much is a bed?
  *one item: use the singular* is.
- How much are two beds?
  *more than one item: use the plural* are.
- How much are a stapler, two pens and a llama?
  *more than one item: use the plural* are. *This question could be asking about the price of the three things listed, or the total price; the correct interpretation will depend on the context.*

With countable items and asking about quantity (or rather, number), you can't use *much,* and have to use *many:*

- How many beds are there?
  *beds are countable; use* many
- *How much beds are there?
  *beds are countable, so you can't use* much
- How much mashed potato would you like?
  *mashed potato is uncountable, so* much *refers to quantity*
- How many scoops of mashed potato would you like?
  *scoops are countable, so use* many *to count them*